# How to sort replies according to comment in a blog post

Tags: php, mysqli, comments, blogs

My question is about how to group replies according to comments in each post. I am a beginner in PHP and I learn by practicing and giving myself tasks. Am working on a blog that uses a comment system as part of its features. I'm finding it difficult grouping replies according to comments.

I have been able to sought the comments according to post by creating a foreign key to the posts id. I tried using the same approach to sought the replies according to comments. That is, I want each reply to sit under the corresponding comments. I created a foreign key to (comments_id) in the replies table and linked it to the id of the comments table.
I therefore used the query below to sought the replies according to comment, which displayed the entire replies. Every post having the same number of replies displayed after the last comment, even when they don’t have up to that number of replies. I have 5 replies, 3 for 1 comment, and 1 each for other 2 comments. But at the end of the last comment in every post, 5 replies will be displayed.
But when I change the first line in my query to:  $r_query = $get_replies = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE comments_id = $id"; Nothing will be displaced.
The comments.php and post.php is presented below. I decided not to remove any part of the code, as every part maybe necessary.

```
$r_query = $get_replies = "SELECT * FROM replies ";
<?php        
                    $r_query = $get_replies = "SELECT * FROM replies";
                    $r_run = mysqli_query($con,$r_query);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($r_run) <= 1){

                    ?>                  
                    <div class="comment">
                       <?php
                        while($r_row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_run)){
                            $r_id = $r_row['id'];
                            $r_name = $r_row['name'];
                            $r_username = $r_row['username'];
                            $r_image = $r_row['image'];
                            $r_reply = $r_row['reply'];
                        ?>
                        <div class="row single-comment user-comment">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <img src="img/<?php echo $r_image; ?>" alt="Profile Picture" class="rounded-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <h4><?php echo ucfirst($r_name);  ?></h4>
                                <span class="time"><?php echo date('M j, Y', strtotime($r_row['date'])); ?></span>
                                <span class="time"><?php echo 'at '.date('h:i a', strtotime($r_row['date'])); ?></span>
                                <p><?php echo $r_reply; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                    </div>
                     <?php  }?>
```

COMMENTS TABLE STRUCTURE WITH SAMPLE DATA

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `posts_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `date`, `name`, `username`, `post_id`, `email`, `website`, `image`, `comment`, `status`, `posts_id`) VALUES
(136, '2019-02-08 01:16:17', 'Val Amasiatu', 'compus', 91, 'valamasiatu@gmail.com', 'avidscholars.com.ng', 'Unknown_Member.jpg', 'Keep it up', 'approve', 91),

### -- Indexes for table `comments`

ALTER TABLE `comments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `comments and posts link` (`posts_id`) USING BTREE;
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables

### -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `comments`

ALTER TABLE `comments`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=155;
-- Constraints for dumped tables

### -- Constraints for table `comments`

ALTER TABLE `comments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Foreign key to posts table` FOREIGN KEY (`posts_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

REPLIES TABLE STRUCTURE WITH SAMPLE DATA

CREATE TABLE `replies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comments_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- Dumping data for table `replies`
INSERT INTO `replies` (`id`, `date`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `image`, `comment`, `status`, `comments_id`) VALUES
(163, '2019-02-08 23:02:23', 'Vall Amasia', 'val', 'cgeneral@gmail.com', 'adult-beard-blur-927022.jpg', '1st reply', 'approve', 151),

### -- Indexes for table `replies`

ALTER TABLE `replies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `Comment and replies relationship` (`comments_id`);
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables

### -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `replies`

ALTER TABLE `replies`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=168;
-- Constraints for dumped tables
-- Constraints for table `replies`
ALTER TABLE `replies`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Foreign key to replies table` FOREIGN KEY (`comments_id`) REFERENCES `comments` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

STRUCTURE AND SAMPLE DATA FOR THE POSTS TABLE

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `author_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `categories` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `post_data` text NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
-- Dumping data for table `posts`
INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `postDate`, `title`, `author`, `author_image`, `image`, `categories`, `tags`, `post_data`, `views`, `status`) VALUES
(42, '2019-02-03 11:21:22', 'What is Lorem Ipsum?', '1234', 'AvePoint.jpg', 'administration-balance-blur-272978.jpg', 'tutorials', 'my, my, my', '

But what i have not been able to do is to find and place this missing closing tag div where it is supposed to be.

', 8, 'publish'),

### -- Indexes for table `posts`

ALTER TABLE `posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `posts`
ALTER TABLE `posts`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=92;
COMMIT;

I needed to have the replies grouped according to their respective comments in any post with comments as well as replies. i.e. the replies coming under the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you might mean something other than "sought". Maybe "sort" or "seek"? Also, there's a lot of code to go through. Do you think you could reduce it to something more like a [mcve]?

Comment: Done as suggested @Don't Panic

Answer (score 0):

Though the approach might be costly, using your idea, this are the steps you ought to take after selecting each comment and lopping through them to print them

1. During each loop, get the comment ID and query the replies table for replies matching that ID
2. When the replies are gotten create an inner loop and output the results

   `$comments = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $postId)";
   while($comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments)){
       echo $comment['message'];
       $replies = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE commentId = $comment['comments_id']);
       while($reply = mysqli_fetch_assoc($replies)){
           echo $reply['message'];
       }
   }`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188136/discussion-on-answer-by-olayemii-how-to-sort-replies-according-to-comment-in-a-b).

Comment: Honestly it seems something is wrong with [], they are both showing different colors in my editor.    $r_query = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE comments_id = $c_row['id']";